# Javascript function works only on one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I'm working on a plugin, however it works for one half now. The problem is that I get a few variables from a checkbox, but the function will only work on the last checked item (in the list) of the checkbox, not for the others.

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('#gap-filtedit input[type=button]').click(function(){
    jQuery('.filter-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      getchecked = jQuery(this).data('rel');

      val = '[gap ';
      console.log(getchecked);

      jQuery('.' + getchecked).each(function(){
        val = val + getchecked + '=';
        name = jQuery(this).find('label').data('id');
        title = jQuery(this).find('input[type=text],select').val();

        if (!title) title = '';
        if (name != 'null') {

          val = val + name + ':' + title + ', ';

        }
      });
    });


    window.send_to_editor( val );
  });
});
```

The log will give me the selected options. However the function after the `console.log` will only work on the last selected in the row.

How to get the function to work for every selected item?

Comment: you're using the same `val` for all iterations...

Comment: you have not used `var` to declare any variables in scope, all of those variables used are global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while looping the checkboxes you have

```
val = '[gap '; // setting the value
```

while looping the form fields you are appending

```
...
val = val + getchecked + '='; // appending
...
val = val + name + ':' + title + ', '; // appending
...
```

now when the inner loop finishes and goes back to the outer loop, your `val` is set back to `[gap` (basically erasing the last inner loops appends)

A solution is to declare the variable within the `click` function and append (rather than set) in the first loop

<kbd>[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzJSZ/)</kbd>

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#gap-filtedit input[type=button]').click(function () {
        var val = ""; // give variable proper scope vs creating a global

        jQuery('.filter-checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            getchecked = jQuery(this).data('rel');

            val += '[gap '; // append instead of set
            console.log(getchecked);

            jQuery('.' + getchecked).each(function () {
                val += getchecked + '=';
                var name = jQuery(this).find('label').data('id');
                var title = jQuery(this).find('input[type=text],select').val();

                if (!title) title = '';
                if (name != undefined) {
                    val += name + ':' + title + ', ';
                }
            });
        });

        window.send_to_editor(val);
    });
});
```

sidenotes:

- scope the other variables (`var title`, `var name`)
- `var name = jQuery(this).find('label').data('id');` will either have a value or be `undefined` (rather than `"null"`)

Comment: Thanks for your respone, I'm following you what you're saying. Now my problem is that I need the output as follow (if there are 2 checkboxes checked: `getchecked=name+title, name+title, name+title, getchecked=name+title, name+ title, name+title` So I'm trying to figure out how I can get the getchecked value out of the each function, but it must be set for every checkbox checked.. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Yes indeed, I figured it out. I only had to change the send to editor button in the function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Do the function within the .each statement:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('#gap-filtedit input[type=button]').click(function(){
            jQuery('.filter-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                    getchecked = jQuery(this).data('rel');

            val = '[gap ';
            console.log(getchecked);

jQuery('.' + getchecked).each(function(){   
        val = val + getchecked + '=';                      
        name = jQuery(this).find('label').data('id');
        title = jQuery(this).find('input[type=text],select').val();     

                    if (!title) title = '';
                        if (name != 'null') {

                val = val + name + ':' + title + ', ';
                window.send_to_editor( val );

                            }
                        });
                    });



                });
            });
```

Comment: This works indeed.. my output is now something like (if 1 option is checked):
`getchecked=name:title, getchecked=name:title, getchecked=name:title.` But what I actually need is something like this:
`getcheck=name:title, name:title, name title` So getchecked must not be in each funtion, however it must come  back for every option checked. Hope you get it what I mean